# Perl script filtering wireshark ethernet packets

Tags: perl, filter, command-line-arguments, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I am developing an inventory agent daemon so I am currently trying to create a perl script that will parse Ethernet packets using the LLDP protocol.

Im using tshark ethernet filters to obtain these details and then print them out

```
@ARGV = ``tshark -i ether proto \0x88cc'`;

while (@ARGV)
{
    my $item =  @ARGV;
    print "$item \n";   
}
```

This results in compilation errors: `Can't exec "tshark"`.

I think I'm not correctly passing the tshark filter options to the command line but as far as I am aware the backticks are used to capture the output of command line arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of `tshark`. But if `tshark -i ether proto \0x88cc` is an executable command from shell try following else please provide more details

```
my @output= `tshark -i ether proto \0x88cc`;
foreach my $item (@output) {
    print "${item}\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error so it appears to be the format of the command. Used the following document to obtain the required commands: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/7/pcap-filter.htm

Comment: @JoshBalta800 In such case, can you please first test it on shell command line? Provide the result if it works fine. Sorry to say that I would be able to help only in `perl` portion.

Comment: having tested this on the command line using #tshark ether proto '0x88cc' I found the tshark package was missing so I ran sudo apt-get to install tshark and this solved the issue.